# Filter Django models based on date comparision

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Subscription models that has an end_date attribute.

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    client = models.OneToOneField(ClientProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(TrainerProfile, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transaction = models.OneToOneField(PaymentHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to send an email to the user having subscription to notify once:

```
(subscription.end_date - timezone.now()).days < 3
```

How would I filter data from django based on these type of comparision in filter() rather than reading all the Subscription objects in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can find 3 days from now. After you can use `end_date__lte` param. Like that:

```
comparing_date =  datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
subscriptions =  Subscription.objects.filter(end_date__lte=comparing_date)
```

Comment: I'm certain that the logic of your answer is wrong as it is now.

Comment: It should be `comparing_date = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)`. The query is correct.

Comment: Exactly. But I wanted him to see that the words he wrote were proper but not not the logic in code.

Comment: But the words are also wrong, because first you need to get the date 3 days from now (not 3 days ago).

Comment: My mistake. You're right but I was able to approach the problem because of the way he suggested it instead of looking for something complicated.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you can convert it date-time logic instead of date. Thanks your warnigs.

Comment: Since this piece of code is to be executed as periodic task using celery I truncated it to avoid sending it 3 times instead of 2.

Comment: I just noticed how things can go wrong with this approach. If the record for that subscription of user is not deleted than mails will be sent everyday starting from 3 days before the end_date. So I think this approach is not inline with (subscription.end_date - timezone.now()).days < 3.

Comment: You can filter with a time window, or you can have a field in your `Subscription` model to record the date on which a mail was sent to avoid sending it again. Would recommend the latter.